# Jenkins: Failed to load Owner[setupProject/13582:null]. Unregistering

Tags: java, jenkins

When I restart jenkins. It raises the below exception.

```
三月 28, 2018 6:01:57 下午 org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.FlowExecutionList$1 computeNext
警告: Failed to load Owner[run_moa_new/362798:null]. Unregistering
java.io.IOException: no such build 362798 in run_moa_new
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun$Owner.run(WorkflowRun.java:711)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun$Owner.get(WorkflowRun.java:719)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.FlowExecutionList$1.computeNext(FlowExecutionList.java:63)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.FlowExecutionList$1.computeNext(FlowExecutionList.java:55)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.FlowExecutionList$ItemListenerImpl.onLoaded(FlowExecutionList.java:170)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:982)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
        at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:235)
```

I have deleted many builds before. It seems that jenkins check those deleted builds when start jenkins, and cost too much time. How to make jenkins not to check those deleted builds  when start jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps to avoid such issues in the future:
Try to cleanup the old builds of the jobs from the filesystem (in $JENKINS_HOME/jobs). Navigate to the folder/directory $JENKINS_HOME/jobs//builds for each project, and delete few or all of the files inside this (which comprise the build history). Following the deletion, you should restart Jenkins or “Reload Configuration from Disk” (both in “Manage Jenkins”) so the links to the deleted builds will get disappeared. Then, install/use the Configuration Slicing Plugin so that you don’t need to perform this bulk deletion again in the future.

It is also possible to purge selectively from the filesystem using the command “find $dir -mtime +$age -rm” where age is the oldest date
you want to keep the build (in days). This should get rid of the builds and the links. Again, you may have to restart or reload
after you are done with it in order for the GUI to show that the builds are no longer available. Please do not forget to backup your $JENKINS_HOME

Comment: I have tried these steps, but it not work.The same exception raised.